# Font-awesome is visible in local but not in server. Using MVC 4

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2015, font-awesome

I used some fontawesome icons in my MVC 4 website menu and in my navbar. When I launch it using Chrome via Visual Studio 2015 all the icons shows up properly but when it comes to publishing into server, none of the icons shows up. I Didn't link font-awesome online and installed folders instead. I dont know what I am missing. Just wonder if anybody have come across a simular issue and solved before?
I would like to add up that, I'm able to upload fontawesome into server but when I open the file it looks empty this might be normal, just wanted to let you know.
(I checked other questions but none of them seems to work so for)
Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: You adding to system font and use it in app?

Comment: just use the CDN here: https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/fontawesome/ and it should take care of your problem

Comment: @mwisnicki It's a font library in my content folder

Comment: @AgilAsadi Make sure you upload all the font files to the server?

Comment: @vivek It is automaticaly uploaded by Visual studio's publishing method, I think?

Comment: @AgilAsadi you can check that using chrome dev tools whether the font is loaded or not/maybe the filpath will be incorrect.

Comment: @vivek umm ok I will see what I can do about it. tnx for ur suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the online refference to load font-awesome.

Comment: tnks for your recommendation. I used that method before but ended up getting wrong link and having fatal error after a while

Comment: Yeah so far CND seem to be the solution in my case. Thanks for your answer buddy.